# Как правильно разделить свой класс между cpp и hpp

Tags: c++

Не могли бы вы мне подсказать как происходит разделение шаблонного класса между файлами cpp и hpp, дабы это было корректно?

Например, сейчас у меня имеется `persistentmap.hpp` и `persistentmap.cpp`

в `persistentmap.hpp` находится данный класс:

```
template <class Key, class FileType, class Compare = std::less<Key>>
    class PersistentMap
    {
    public:
        typedef int size_type;
        typedef std::pair<Key, FileType> value_type;
        typedef FileType mapped_type;
        typedef AVL_Tree<Key, FileType> tree;
        typedef PersistentMapProxy<Key, mapped_type, Compare> Proxy;

    private:
        std::string dirName;
        tree *strom;
        Compare comp;
    public:

        typedef typename tree::iterator iterator;
        typedef typename tree::const_iterator const_iterator;

        //iterators
            iterator begin()
            {
                //iterator::a = t;      
                return strom->begin();
            }

            iterator end()
            {
                return strom->end();
            }

        //constructors
            PersistentMap(std::string ag) :dirName(ag) 
            { 
            //boosttrap
                path p(ag);
                if (!fs::exists(p))
                    fs::create_directory(ag);
                strom=new tree(dirName);
            };

            ~PersistentMap()
            {
                delete strom;
            }

        //operators
            const Proxy operator[] (Key key)
            {
                return Proxy(*this, key);
            }


        //methods
            std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& a)
            {
                int count = strom->getCount();
                iterator it = iterator(strom->insert(a));
                if (count< strom->getCount())
                    return std::make_pair(it, true);
                else
                    return std::make_pair(it, false);
            }

            iterator find(const Key& a)
            {
                    return iterator(*strom->findKey(a));
            }

            const_iterator find(const Key& a) const
            {
                return const_iterator(*strom->findKey(a));
            }

            iterator erase(const_iterator a)
            {
                iterator prev = a++;
                erase((*prev).first);
                return a;
            }

            void erase(iterator first, iterator last) 
            {
                iterator it;
                iterator prev= first++;
                for (it = first; it != last; prev=it++)
                {
                         strom->erase((*prev).first);
                }
                 strom->erase((*prev).first);
            }

            size_type erase(const Key& k) 
            {
                 strom->erase(k);
                return strom->getCount();
            }
    };
```

Тогда как `persistentmap.cpp` пуст.

Я понимаю, что по-хорошему тела функций нужно вынести за пределы hpp, но я не представляю, как это сделать корректно.

Буду очень рад примеру и возможно объяснению.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Начнём с начала. Когда Вы определяете обычный класс:

```
class test {
    int _a;
public:
    void set(int a);
    int get(a);
}
```

То при реализации методов вне класса указываете класс, которому они принадлежат:

```
void test::set(int a) {
    _a = a;
}

int test::get() {
    return _a;
}
```

---

Когда же используете шаблонный класс:

```
template<class T>
class test {
    T _a;
public:
    void set(T a);
    T get(a);
}
```

То нужно описывать шаблон и также его параметры при указании класса:

```
template<class T>
void test<T>::set(T a) {
    _a = a;
}

template<class T>
T test<T>::get() {
    return _a;
}
```

---

А теперь важный момент, на который нужно обратить внимание. Шаблонный класс не должен реализовываться в `cpp` файле, реализация должна подключаться вместе с описанием класса в заготовочном файле, иначе получите ошибку компиляции `Undefined symbols`. Причина в том, что шаблонные классы, функции сами по себе не существуют, они создаются при компиляции с типами, которые Вы используете в коде. Если реализация методов не описывается до использования шаблона, то она и не создаётся для нужных типов, отсюда и ошибка.

Поэтому для отделения реализации шаблонного класса нужно использовать другой подход. Я, к примеру, объявление класса делаю в файле вроде `test.h`, а реализацию в `test.hpp`. При этом, после объявления класса в первом файле находится строка `#include "test.hpp"`, чтобы реализация шаблонных методов всегда была вместе с описанием самого шаблонного класса.

---

Можно реализацию методов хранить и в `cpp` файле. В этом случае Ва просто будет вручную инстанцировать шаблон с нужными типами. Можно просто указать какой-нибудь метод. Для класса выше пример такой:

```
template void test<int>::set(int a);
```

Или указать только класс:

```
template class test<std::string>;
```

Comment: но что если я делаю шаблонный класс по заданию,  и в солюшене задания имеются и cpp и hpp

Comment: Можно и так, сейчас дополню.

Comment: @Demolver взгляните.

Comment: а если я сделаю вот так `template <class Key, class value, class Compare>
 Map<Key, value, Compare>::Map()
 {
  
  //тело 
 };` то есть я как бы для реализации тела функции заранее создал сверху темлпейт

Comment: @Demolver да, это то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: Что то не понятно - сначала Вы пишите, что "Шаблонный класс не должен реализовываться в cpp файле" и буквально через несколько строк уже пишите - "Я, к примеру, объявление класса делаю в файле вроде test.h, а РЕАЛИЗАЦИЮ в test.hpp".

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае этого делать не требуется, так как у вас шаблонный класс. Все шаблоны инстанцируются в месте где в него подставляются конкретные типы и константы. А это происходит, как вы понимаете, в других единицах трансляции, то есть других файлах `.cpp`. Инстанцирование означает что компилятор генерирует конкретную реализацию типа по данному шаблону.

А файл `persistentmap.cpp` вообще не нужен и его нужно удалить.

Comment: Мне по заданию сказано что нужно заполнить оба файла, и hpp и cpp? что можете в данном случае посоветовать?